# Creating two dimentional array in for-loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I want to create an array in a for-loop so i can adjust the size ($i) of the array.
I've tried this:

```
$array = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    array_push($array,
        $i => array(
            "id" => "",
            "option" => ""
        ) 
    );
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in ...

I'v also tried to make it a string by doing `$i.""` on line 4 but that doesn't seem to work either. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More idiomatic would be:

```
$array = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $array[$i] = array(
                "id" => "",
                "option" => "") ;
}
```

However note that this will give you array indexes from 1-5. Arrays are usually indexed from 0:

```
$array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $array[$i] = array(
                "id" => "",
                "option" => "") ;
}
```

But this can be done without specifying the key:

```
$array = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $array[] = array(
                "id" => "",
                "option" => "") ;
}
```

Comment: I would do it this way without specifying the key. Far easier unless you require the key.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$array = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $array[$i] = array(
            "id" => "",
            "option" => ""
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$i =>`

```
$array = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    array_push($array, array(
            "id" => "",
            "option" => ""
        ) 
    );
}
```